# WebSockets over SPDY

Tags: node.js, websocket, spdy

I'm learning about real-time data web applications and I have build some small chat app with Node.js and WebSockets. I was able to implement SPDY for the HTTPS traffic (the static pages) but I can't find a way to have the WebSocket connection to also use the SPDY connection. So now I have 2 TCP connections.

I have found several old articles about WebSockets over SPDY but these are all talking about how it's maybe possible in the future. Since I can't find any recent articles, let alone examples of how to do this, can I conclude that this is not possible yet?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but i think that is not possible. Websockets use a different protocol and a different uri schema (ws and wss uri). Sdpy works on HTTP.